# VSTO VB type for loop for hiding sheets

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm dealing with a problem.

I try to add ribbon and some buttons to hide and show sheets.

So I used the codes below but I couldn't managed. Sheet names in vb are starting with "S".

For example sheet names(S0,S1,S2,S3.....,S10)

```
Private Sub BtnIslemPortfoy_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles BtnIslemPortfoy.Click

        Dim i As Integer



        For i = 1 To 10
            Dim syf As Excel.Worksheet = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.Worksheets("S" & i)
            syf.Visible = false

        Next i


        Globals.S3.Visible = True
        Globals.S4.Visible = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the code? Have you tried running it under the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

You may try setting the `Visible` property to the [XlSheetVisibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlsheetvisibility) value. To display a sheet you need to use the `xlSheetVisible` value.